# Sorting on timestamp column in My Sql - not varchar column

Tags: mysql

I ma trying to sort SQL tuples based on a column filed which is of timestamp datatype.

The data in the table is something like this :

```
 id      attribute   value      updated
-------------------------------------------------
'3449'   'HEIGHT'    '12'      '2013-11-30 03:20:25'
'3449'   'HEIGHT'    '15'      '2013-12-10 03:20:25'


select *, count(1) as cnt from attribute_table 
where id ='3449'
group by id,attribute having cnt > 1
ORDER BY updated;
```

The output is some thing like this, regardless of the fact that I add ASC/DESC parameter at the end of ORDER BY statement, the result remains the same.

```
 id      attribute   value      updated
-------------------------------------------------
'3449'   'HEIGHT'    '12'      '2013-11-30 03:20:25'
```

The datatype of updated column is `timestamp`, and not `varchar` as other similar questions have had on SO.

How do I sort by updated column ?

Comment: based on your grouping there, you're only going to get one row from that sample data anyway. ordering won't help because you're not using an aggregate function on the updated column, mysql chooses the value for you

Comment: Yes, but I want to get the latest row.

Comment: the latest row per group or just the latest row of all?

Comment: latest row per id, attribute on updated column

Comment: thats what i figured, but clarity is always good

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using aggregates, `group by` in mysql takes the first rows of all the rows that are grouped to one row.

Since there are 2 rows that satisfy your group condition so the first (i.e. the top) row is picked for the result set.

you, somehow, need to bring it on the top. A possible turn around, is to sort the result set first, bring the row on top and perform group by.

```
 select *, count(1) as cnt from (select * from attribute_table order by 
 updated desc ) as alias 
 where id ='3449'
 group by id,attribute having cnt > 1
 ORDER BY updated;
```

Comment: It gives Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: try now @LearningToDesign just edited it..since I am not executing it on mysql client i forgot to add the alias of derived table.

Comment: @LearningToDesign be careful. the explanation here is incorrect, as is the answerers understanding of how group by works. mysql does not guarantee that it will choose the 'first row' to fill those other values. please see the details of my answer for why this is

Comment: @pala_ can you give me any reference link or doc that explains it? As far I have been seen, mysql returns the first value of the row.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo the reference link is in my answer, as is the explanation - but here it is again: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html.  Just because it appears to work, does not mean it will always work, or be guaranteed to work across versions, or different storage engines, or any number of other variables. in other words, it is not deterministic

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to this type of problem is a two step process.  First, find the latest row for each id:

```
select id, attribute, max(updated) last_updated
  from <your_table>
  group by id, attribute
```

Next, we need to join that result, back to the table again to get the rest of the data.

```
select t.*
  from <your_table> t
    inner join (
      select id, attribute, max(updated) last_updated
        from <your_table>
        group by id, attribute
    ) q
    on t.id = q.id
      and t.updated = q.last_updated
      and t.attribute = q.attribute
```

And that should give you the result you want.

[quick demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21534/4)

The reason your attempt doesn't work, is down to the way that mysql handles grouping for fields that aren't used in the `group by` clause, or used in an aggregate function.

It is in fact, a convenience that mysql allows you to select fields in that matter at all, most (if not all) other rdbms will throw an error if you try and do that.

[12.16.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) will give you the run down, but the important section is this:

> You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding
>   unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful
>   primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in
>   the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose
>   any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values
>   chosen are indeterminate.

And that's why it isn't choosing the date or value that you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to identify highest ranking record per `id`, `attribute`:

```
SELECT id, attribute, value, updated
FROM (
SELECT value, updated,
       @row_number:= CASE WHEN @id = id AND @attr = attribute THEN @row_number+1
                          ELSE 1
                     END AS rn,
       @id:=id AS id,
       @attr:=attribute AS attribute
FROM attribute_table, (SELECT @row_number:=0, @id:=0, @attr:='') AS vars
ORDER BY id, attribute, updated DESC ) t
WHERE t.rn =1
```

`rn = 1` predicate will select those records having the *most recent* `updated` value per `id`, `attribute`.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2d74/2)

**EDIT:**

Taking into consideration the comments by @pala_ this is how the query should look like:

```
SELECT id, attribute, value, updated
FROM (
SELECT id, attribute, value, updated, 
       if (@id = id AND @attr = attribute, 
           if (@id:=id, 
              if (@attr:=attribute, @row_number:= @row_number + 1, @row_number:= @row_number + 1),
              if (@attr:=attribute, @row_number:= @row_number + 1, @row_number:= @row_number + 1)
           ),   
           if (@id:=id, 
              if (@attr:=attribute, @row_number:= 1, @row_number:= 1),
              if (@attr:=attribute, @row_number:= 1, @row_number:= 1)
           )   
       ) AS rn
FROM attribute_table, (SELECT @row_number:=0, @id:='', @attr:='') AS vars
ORDER BY id, attribute, updated DESC ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e0a0/2)

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complicated (and potentially broken) method of accomplishing a simple thing. You have no control over the order that mysql evaluates the fields in a select statement, so while it may occasionally work that your variables have the value you expect, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @pala_ Variables are being applied on an *ordered set*. Check this out: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: I don't need to. Your assignment of id and attr happens outside of the case statement and may be evaluated either before or after your case statement

Comment: @pala_ Well, I have no producion-level experience in MySQL. But, I have seen numerous posts here is SO and blog articles mentioning this exact method as a way to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function in MySQL.

Comment: [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) is a good place to start, specifically the section around this quote: `However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.`.  You CAN accomplish per group ranking with variables, but you need to use nested conditionals - [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115532/sum-the-values-of-a-column-based-on-a-group-of-values-from-another-column/30115781#30115781)